# Issue in printing html table with large amount of width

Tags: javascript, printing, html-table, internet-explorer-9

I have html table with ten rows and one `<td>` for each row who's width is more the browser view width, while printing this in IE 9 it prints only things what in view. I want to print whole table, how can i do this?

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TKDzT/1/show/) sample, this is the table which I need to print. Please help me to do this.

Comment: Are you using the `Shrink to fit` option?